# Custom HID UPS not detected by UPower in Linux

Tags: usb, usb-device, linux, hid

My original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75910694/custom-hid-ups-the-host-does-not-update-the-data-from-reports

I'm looking to build a USB HID device (uninterruptible power supply) using Raspberry Pi Pico, and currently I'm having trouble sending data to the host (PC running Ubuntu).

The USB device is visible in `lsusb`:

```
user@user-HP:~$ sudo lsusb -vvvd 051D:0003
[sudo] password for user: 

Bus 001 Device 022: ID 051d:0003 American Power Conversion UPS
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x051d American Power Conversion
  idProduct          0x0003 UPS
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 American Power Conversion
  iProduct                2 UPS
  iSerial                 3 123456
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0029
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      75
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               1
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Here I'm using vendor and product IDs of APC, because `udev` seems to detect power devices based on those (source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297093/custom-hid-compliant-ups-based-on-arduino-leonardo-micro-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-1).

Here's the HID report descriptor of the device:

```
root@user-HP:~# cat /sys/kernel/debug/hid/0003\:051D\:0003.0010/rdesc 
05 84 09 04 a1 01 09 10 a1 00 85 01 75 08 95 01 09 fd 79 01 b1 03 09 fe 79 02 b1 03 09 ff 79 03 b1 03 09 12 a1 00 85 02 05 85 75 01 95 04 17 00 00 00 00 27 01 00 00 00 09 44 09 45 09 46 09 47 81 82 95 01 75 04 81 01 c0 c0 c0 

  INPUT(2)[INPUT]
    Field(0)
      Physical(Power Device.Battery)
      Application(Power Device.UPS)
      Usage(4)
        Battery System.Charging
        Battery System.Discharging
        Battery System.0046
        Battery System.0047
      Logical Minimum(0)
      Logical Maximum(1)
      Report Size(1)
      Report Count(4)
      Report Offset(0)
      Flags( Variable Absolute Volatile )
  FEATURE(1)[FEATURE]
    Field(0)
      Physical(Power Device.BatterySystem)
      Application(Power Device.UPS)
      Usage(1)
        Power Device.iManufacturer
      Report Size(8)
      Report Count(1)
      Report Offset(0)
      Flags( Constant Variable Absolute )
    Field(1)
      Physical(Power Device.BatterySystem)
      Application(Power Device.UPS)
      Usage(1)
        Power Device.iProduct
      Report Size(8)
      Report Count(1)
      Report Offset(8)
      Flags( Constant Variable Absolute )
    Field(2)
      Physical(Power Device.BatterySystem)
      Application(Power Device.UPS)
      Usage(1)
        Power Device.iSerialNumber
      Report Size(8)
      Report Count(1)
      Report Offset(16)
      Flags( Constant Variable Absolute )

Battery System.Charging ---> Sync.Report
Battery System.Discharging ---> Sync.Report
Battery System.0046 ---> Sync.Report
Battery System.0047 ---> Sync.Report
```

Parsed:

```
USAGE_PAGE (Power Device)
USAGE (UPS)
COLLECTION (Application)
  USAGE (Battery System)
  COLLECTION (Physical)
    REPORT_ID (1)
    REPORT_SIZE (8)
    REPORT_COUNT (1)

    USAGE (iManufacturer)
    STRING_INDEX (1)
    FEATURE (Constant Variable Absolute)

    USAGE (iProduct)
    STRING_INDEX (2)
    FEATURE (Constant Variable Absolute)

    USAGE (iSerialNumber)
    STRING_INDEX (3)
    FEATURE (Constant Variable Absolute)

    USAGE (Battery)
    COLLECTION (Physical)
      REPORT_ID (2)
      USAGE_PAGE (Battery System)
      REPORT_SIZE (1)
      REPORT_COUNT (4)
      LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
      LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
      USAGE (Charging)
      USAGE (Discharging)
      USAGE (Fully Charged)
      USAGE (Fully Discharged)
      INPUT (Variable Absolute Volatile)

      REPORT_COUNT (1)
      REPORT_SIZE (4)
      INPUT (Constant Array)
    END_COLLECTION
  END_COLLECTION
END_COLLECTION
```

For now, I'm trying to get the device to signal a *charging* state to the host. The reports it's sending look correct to me:

```
root@user-HP:~# usbhid-dump -a 1:24 -e all
001:024:000:DESCRIPTOR         1680968580.207971
 05 84 09 04 A1 01 09 10 A1 00 85 01 75 08 95 01
 09 FD 79 01 B1 03 09 FE 79 02 B1 03 09 FF 79 03
 B1 03 09 12 A1 00 85 02 05 85 75 01 95 04 17 00
 00 00 00 27 01 00 00 00 09 44 09 45 09 46 09 47
 81 82 95 01 75 04 81 01 C0 C0 C0

Starting dumping interrupt transfer stream
with 1 minute timeout.

001:024:000:STREAM             1680968580.230530
 02 01

001:024:000:STREAM             1680968580.281468
 02 01

001:024:000:STREAM             1680968580.332369
 02 01
```

The problem, however, is that UPower on Linux is not detecting this state:

```
root@user-HP:~# upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/ups_hiddev0
  native-path:          /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev0
  vendor:               APC
  model:                UPS
  serial:               123456
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat Apr  8 18:44:30 2023 (9 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  ups
    present:             yes
    state:               empty
    warning-level:       none
    percentage:          0%
    icon-name:          'battery-empty-symbolic'
```

This happens no matter what fields I include in the report descriptor and the report. I even attempted to swap out the report descriptor for a mouse and to send the corresponding reports, but to no effect.

I previously had some issues with USB endpoints, which seem to be fixed now. Here's a sample from Wireshark:
[![Wireshark request][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

However, this has not changed anything about how the device is displayed in the OS, which makes me think that there is another issue, or that the one I've had is not completely fixed. Any advice on whether there's anything I need to pay special attention to in the outputs above would be appreciated.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/znkzR.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6756z.png